Deciding the language $0^k1^{k+m}0^m$ in O(nlogn)
I believe the language $0^k1^{k+m}0^m$ (with $k, m \ge 0$) is decideable by a standard TM with one tape and one read/write head in O(nlogn).
Basically you can use very similar logic to that you would use for deciding $0^m1^m$ in O(nlogn), i.e crossing off every other 0 and 1 at each step and making sure parities match up, after first validating the input format which you can do in a few passes which are O(n).
There is some added complexity here of having the 0's not contiguous but I sketched through this in terms of the state machine required and believe it does not impose a severe penalty in terms of computational complexity (e.g. at most adds constant multiple of N to logic).
Is this right or am I missing something big?

wdym by "the 0's not contiguous"? should it be 0^k 1^k+m 0^m?

Yes, so sorry just saw the typo - corrected.

this is a bit of a cop-out, but since TM can (usually) detect edges of the tape - you can easily transform your problem to be on a looping tape instead
just "save" the state you reached the border with (at most doubling TM states), transfer to the other side - and then resume
If I understand how the normal O(nlogn) algorithm works, it should be easy to adapt it to walk only in a single direction on a looping tape. Overhead to transfer machine head from one side to the other will only double the runtime
after doing that, $0^k 1^{k+m} 0^m$ case is no different from $1^{k+m} 0^{k+m}$ that you're confident in
